Troubleshoot Simple MOSFET switching circuit (automotive 12V - 5A)
I need to troubleshoot the circuit I created to power an LED strip that I put in my car. My issue is specifically connected to the MOSFET switching circuit. (I don't want to use relays because they are quite big).
I'm a novice in electronics, so I may have misunderstood something basic about how transistors work.
Depending on the number of LEDs, my load can draw between 1.5A to 5A. I am using a DC-DC step down module called Mini 560 that I purchased from AliExpress. The step down module is capable of providing 5A at 5V and has been functioning effectively up to this point.
Although I don't have a datasheet for the buck converter, MisterHW's detailed write-up is a great resource.

The following is the diagram for the mosfet switching circuit:

And My full circuit is this:


CGND is the Car Ground or Battery -
CVDD is the Battery +
SGN is a signal, usually the low beam + (12V), I believe this should be more than the transistor gate threshold voltage of 2.5V.

Everything works as expected when the car is turned off and the low beam is on. After inspecting the battery, I found it to be approximately 12V, and the same for the low beam +.
When I turn on the car and switch the low beam on, the circuit does not turn on. At this point, the battery is approx 14V and the low beam + is approx 11V.
If I have the low beam on, and then I turn the car on, the circuit stays on for a bit, but it crashes the ESP32 probably due to low voltage and then it switches the circuit off.
If I have the car on and connect the SGN to the battery +, everything works again.
Questions:
Can I fix the circuit by adding another transistor and using a P Channel MOSFET? Something like this:

I also looked into smart high-side power switch PROFET, like BTS6142DAUMA1 but it uses logic of 3.3V or 5V and I am using 12V. If I don't know the voltage of the signal, can I still use it?
Would a solid-state relay be more appropriate for this? The ones capable of handling 5A are quite big and expensive.
Why is this circuit working on a newer car (2021 with LED lights) but not on my old car (2012 with halogen headlights)?
Edit 1:
I have redesigned the switching portion of the circuit using other components:
Transistor: BC846A
P-Channel MOSFET: DMP10H400SK3-13

Edit 2:
The new circuit follows the same pattern as the previous one, functioning properly when the car is turned off but becoming unstable when it is turned on.
I am going to hook up an oscilloscope and check everything. Could it be noise? The circuit works when I connect SGN directly to the battery.
Edit 3:
I finally managed to connect the oscilloscope and check the battery and signal voltages.
Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points to post multiple links, so I will upload everything in a single image.
I apologize for the poor quality pictures. It was nighttime when I took them.

After researching online, I discovered that a significant number of car manufacturers are utilizing PWM to lower the voltage from 14V (Car On) to 12V to enhance the lifespan.
I measured the current draw across the SGN line and found it to be around 1.15mA.

Circuit GND is switched, was this intentional? (You seem to have wired the buck converter as if it's isolated.) Are there any other connections from GND to chassis ground?

What make and model are your old and new cars?

@TimWilliams I connected the buck converter - to the drain, I just got the first circuit and added to my source, which is the buck converter. There are no other connections to chassis ground, I thought when the transistor is on it would connect the circuit GND to the car GND, maybe I got that wrong.

@MrGerber It's a dodge grand caravan 2012 and a dodge durango 2021. I didn't actually connect the CVDD and CGND to the battery, I saw two pins that I assume it's used to jump start the car and I used those. I am not sure if it's connected directly to the battery. I think the battery is hidden somewhere under one one of the seats.

I am concerned about these two parts of your circuit: part 1, part 2 My question: How is GND connected to CGND? Assuming the issues with GND and CGND are sorted, then the next issue is how the buck converter is wired. If it is not isolated, then its IN- and OUT- pins are likely to be connected together, it which case GND is connected to CGND when Q1 is on. If you provide a link to the datasheet for this part, we may be able to assist further.

My assumption was that GND was the same as CGND while Q1 was on, you are correct. I think I should have utilized the same name for CGND and GND in the circuit. I will include a picture of the buck converter, but I don't have a datasheet for it.

It not usually a good idea to have the GND of one circuit not being tied permanently to the GND of its parent circuit.   Better if GND is permanently connected to CGND.  That means that your existing circuit is not suitable, you will need to swap over to the circuit you proposed that uses P-chan MOSFET to switch the positive power to the buck converter.   However, there is a change required: change R1 from 200Ω to 1kΩ or even 10kΩ.  The value to choose will depends on the max and min range of voltage expected for SGN.

Thank you for your help. I made some changes to the switching part of the circuit and will give it a go.

@Sesori  Did you manage to get it to work?

Thanks for following up, I updated my question yesterday with the new circuit. Unfortunately it doesn't work either. I am thinking it is the wire I am using for SGN (halogen headlight +). I tried disconnecting the halogen bulb and it works fine. The other thing I noticed, is when I have the low beam off but the bulb disconnected I read 4.44V , but when I connect the bulb again it goes to about 60mV. I just don't understand how the circuit doesn't turn on when I have 11V on the SGN, but it works when the car is off.

Some ideas to try:  1.  Remove Z1, in case it is installed reverse.  2. Change R9 to 1k.

Sorry, please ignore previous comment, just realised you had updated the circuit.  Some ideas to try:  1.  Put an R & C across base-emitter of Q2.  2. Remove BUCKCONVERTER and replace with simple LED load.  Do these changes one at a time then check circuit operation after each change.

Thanks @Fabio Barone, my question was updated again with additional information. I believe an RC filter should work, so I am currently working on it.

As previously mentioned in my editing. The problem was that the car uses PWM to artificially reduce the voltage from 14V to 12V when the car is on and the alternator is running.
I believe that the circuit keeps switching, which is the reason why the buck converter does not maintain 5V to turn the system on.
To solve my problem, I had to add a capacitor between the base and emitter of Q2. I used a 10uF capacitor.
I am thankful for the help of everyone and I want to express a special thanks to @Fabio Barone. Below is his version of the circuit, tested and working.


Good result.  Question: is node CVDD constant, or is it PWM as well (like SGN)?  There may be room for improvement, for example, reducing the size of the capacitor from 47uF to < 1uF, depending on other considerations.

The CVDD node is directly connected to the battery +, so it maintains a constant 12V. It goes up to 14V when the alternator is on and charging the battery, but it remains constant. I will try different capacitor values and different cars to ensure that it works in every scenario. Since the circuit doesn't need to turn on or off quickly I can be flexible picking a capacitor value, I'll try 1uF and below next.

Suggest put a new R in series with base pin of Q2 of your new schematic.  Value about 470K to 2.2meg  ohms.  C7 voltage rating must be higher than peak voltage at SGN.  So, 25V or 35V should be ok.   The much higher R value means value of C7 can be greatly reduced.  May need to add another R across Q2 BE to help it turn off, same value R as for the new R added at base pin.

I'm curious if pulling down the SGN will cause the ECU to generate any codes. My measurement was 4.4V when the lamp is disconnected and 20mV when it is connected and low beam is off. I am not sure if the computer uses voltages to check if the lamp is burnt. You also mentioned that C7 voltage rating must be higher than peak voltage at SGN, but the voltage at Q2 base is about 700mV because of the diode and the 10K resistor, does the capacitor voltage rating matters? Did you mention to add another resistor after R5 or change value? I made another example here

I have edited the last schematic you posted into an answer (since that is the only way I can send you an image).  Note that C7 now sees the peak voltage of SGN.  Q2 is turned on by a new R (470K) to one side of C7.  Turn-off of Q2 is assisted by 470K placed across its B-E.  The key idea here: C7 filters SGN, not Q2 Vbe.

@FabioBarone - "I have edited the last schematic you posted into an answer (since that is the only way I can send you an image)". That is not true. Although comments can't display images, you can add an image link in a comment using this technique. The draft answer must not be submitted. || It seems you are turning answers into discussions which is misusing the site. I thought I had explained this (including the ability to upload images using a draft answer and then place the link into a comment) to you before?

@FabioBarone - Please remember, we are not just here to answer the OP's question. The purpose of the site is to collect questions & answers for future readers. This requires that answers are only used to answer the original question - not for troubleshooting and not for showing images to the OP. A new reader should be able to read the question and see an attempted solution to the original question in each of the answers. If an answer is used for anything else, that is site misuse.

@SamGibson  Noted.  Please be assured that I am not intending to "misuse" this site.  I will remove my latest answer and try to paste the images as links, something that I have not yet figured out how to do.  Wont be able to do this for some time, busy with other things right now.  Cheers.

@FabioBarone - (a) Here is the syntax to link to that latest image: [schematic](https://i.sstatic.net/bmRi987U.png) which displays like this: schematic i.e. square brackets around the link text & parentheses around the URL of the image. No spaces. (b) There's more info on link syntax in the editing help. In comments, use the "inline link" style shown on that page. More info about linking in comments here too. (c) Or I can help you make a chatroom with the OP. Images display inline in chat.

Referring to one of the comments by moderator @SamGibson above: "answers are only used to answer the original question".  // Therefore, please EDIT your original post to include the last schematic you posted.  I will then post an answer to that post with my recommended changes to that last schematic.  Seems this is required to abide by site rules.  Cheers.

@FabioBarone - Hi, I know you're trying to help, but the OP has answered the original question. Therefore it is now too late to change the original question, since there is an answer (their answer) to that original question. So changing the question isn't a valid option.. || This is a problem because the OP's self-answer is not really an answer, as they are asking for help with that. That approach again breaks SE rules, as their "answer" has really become a question :( || The only way forward I can see is for the OP to ask a new question if they need help with a new schematic.

(continued) You can troubleshoot the new question in comments or chat on that new question. And if you solve it, then obviously you can post an answer there. || As I said, this is an unusual situation (which I have seen before), caused by an OP posting an answer, but then asking for help with that answer (like on a forum). That is not how Stack Exchange works :( If an OP posts an answer, it should be treated like any other answer - just vote on it. Don't let an answer (especially a self-answer) become a question. || Thanks for your help with this.

@SamGibson Noted, thank you.

@Sesori Please follow the rules of this website (ask a new question) & I will post my answer under that.  You can link the new question to your original question.  Cheers

Apologies for the confusion. Should I remove the circuit image from my answer and refer to Fabio's answer instead if he posts an answer with his version of the circuit? I am not sure what to ask in a new question, and people coming here would not be able to see the final version of the circuit. Even if I mention another question, it's possible for people to overlook it.
